# Unity ARCore XR Plugin package initialization not completed warning after adding package, black screen on android

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm very new to Unity, and I just followed a few youtube tutorials to try and get started with ARCore. But when I install the ARCore XR Plugin with AR Foundation from the package manager, I get a warning saying

"ARCore XR Plugin package initialization not completed. You will need to create any instances of the loaders and settings manually before you can use the intended XR Plug-in Package."

I have disabled multithreaded rendering and I'm running the APK on realme X, which supports ARCore as per the official device list. On running the basic cube AR application, the app doesn't ask for camera permissions and I'm stuck on a black screen. Is there anything I'm missing?

Unity version 2020.3.0f1 Personal,
AR Foundation 4.0.12,
ARCore XR Plugin 4.0.12

I tried these on multiple versions, only to end up with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Although the black screen can occur because of many reasons, try to go to
Player Settings -> XR Plug-in Management -> In the Android tab check "ARCore" under Plug-in Providers

Comment: cant, its greyed out